# Access control to web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, certificate

This is what I wish to achieve:

My ASP.NET web service is hosted on a server called **//service**. I want to control access to the web service by server and by application as well. What I mean here is if I have two ASP.NET web applications (app1 and app2) hosted on a server called **//web1** and I only want **//web1/app1** to be able to call the web service. I know that I can grant access to the IP address of **//web1** but that would allow both **//web1/app1** and **//web1/app2** access to the web service.

I am thinking about using an SSL certificate as I don't want the web application to handle the login/password. on **//service**, I will grant access to the ip of **//web1** and map a client certificate from **//web1** to a windows account and this will allow only applications from **//web1** to access. But then how do I further control the access to only **//web1/app1**?

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard [HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to control which applications have access to your web service.

Credentials are passed in the **Authorization** header with each request. Every web service client (i.e. //web1/app1) should have its own credentials, so if //web1/app2 tried to connect to the web service without providing recognized credentials, it would be denied access.

I recommend using SSL to encrypt all traffic, so that authentication information and other sensitive data is secure.

Here are a few articles that may be helpful:

- [HTTP Security and ASP.NET Web Services (see Authentication section)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996415.aspx#httpsecurity_topic3)
- [Authentication in ASP.NET Web Services](http://progtutorials.tripod.com/Authen.htm)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

A certificate secures the transmission between the client and server domain. It doesn't really work to have multiple certificates for multiple subdirectories.

What you'd want to do is to create a login service that returns a token. You then use that token to manage the session on the server side and the client uses it along with every subsequent request to access and execute the available services. (can this token access this webservice? t/f)

You're going to have to give the client access to some sort of credentials. Whether that is a certificate exchange or a user/pass you're going to have to figure out who the client actually is.