# HttpWebRequest for HTTPS got 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: c#, soap, office365

I am getting an error message "403 Forbidden" on calling the GetListCollection method from my C# project. The sharepoint version in online 2013 and URL is starts with HTTPS.

The code for my HTTP header request is:

```
string _url = "https://my.sharepoint.com/"+ "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

string soapStr =
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                    <soap:Body>
                        <GetListCollection xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"" />
                    </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);

req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection\"");
req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword);
req.Method = "POST";

            using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapStr = string.Format(soapStr);
                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                    stmw.Write(soapStr);
                }
            }
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong or what else I need to do?

In fiddler,I got the following response.

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required: https://my.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx&Source=%2f_vti_bin%2fLists.asmx
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url: https://my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx
X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; %e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%8c%e6%8b%92%e5%90%a6%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%80%82%e3%81%93%e3%81%ae%e5%a0%b4%e6%89%80%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%82%92%e9%96%8b%e3%81%8f%e5%89%8d%e3%81%ab%e3%80%81Web+%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e5%8f%82%e7%85%a7%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%80%81%e8%87%aa%e5%8b%95%e7%9a%84%e3%81%ab%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%82%aa%e3%83%97%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%92%e9%81%b8%e6%8a%9e%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%80%82
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: 7dbaf69c-a0f4-1000-ba3c-f5906d15f5d7
request-id: 7dbaf69c-a0f4-1000-ba3c-f5906d15f5d7
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 66
SPIisLatency: 0
X-IDCRL_AUTH_PARAMS_V1: IDCRL Type="BPOSIDCRL", EndPoint="/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/", RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.3819
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 04:26:16 GMT
Content-Length: 13

403 FORBIDDEN
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs since [NetworkCredential class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could **not** be utilized in Office 365, Microsoft supports [claims-based authentication in Office 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx).

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) has been released that contains
[SharePointOnlineCredentials class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) to access SharePoint Online resources.

### How to consume SharePoint Web Services in Office 365

The following example demonstrates how to authenticate request in Office 365:

```
string endpointUrl = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
var envelope = 
                  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                  "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                    "<soap:Body>" +
                       "<GetListCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\" />" +
                    "</soap:Body>" +
                  "</soap:Envelope>";


var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(endpointUrl);
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
request.Credentials = GetCredentials(userName, password);
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
request.Method = "POST";
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
    {
       streamWriter.Write(envelope);
    }
}


using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
     using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
     {
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        var data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     }         
}
```

where

```
 public static SharePointOnlineCredentials GetCredentials(string userName, string password)
 {
     var securePassword = new SecureString();
     foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
     return  new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

403 Forbidden is a typical error code to receive when trying to reach a service over HTTPS and not having set the certificate properly on the client side. That being said, the problem might be in multiple places and it also depends on how authentication is set up on the server you're trying to reach.

I think [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librarY/aa702579%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will be helpful to boot. Then see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399155/http-status-403-forbidden-exception-using-certificate-to-authenticate-asp-net-w), as the discussion points to several problems and ideas that will probably help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Now I am trying for Remote authentication in SharePoint Online as the follow link:                            http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: I'm glad I've helped you with your problem, please up the answer if you really found it useful. I checked the link you provided it discusses sharepoint authentication, but I recon that your problem comes from using SSL and is related to the security certificate.

Comment: I got the answer.When SP Online,there is need to request SAML Token and set Cookies as the following link. http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Congrats! Do post it in more detail here, so others benefit as well.

Comment: Ok.I will post in detail after complete.